# como muestros mis datos sin las etiquetas que guardo tinymce?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

tengo un pequeño problema, lo que pasa es que estoy haciendo un foro en laravel, y donde se supone que ponen la descripcion o codigo eh integrado tinymce para ello, de guardar los datos en la DB no es el problema, lo que estoy haciendo es hacer un select en el controlador y lo mando a la vista con todos los datos como un array, el cual lo recorro con un  forech
pero este me muestra con las etiquetas tal cual se guardo en la db y para ello uso este codigo y me lo muestra en texto plano, lo que yo quiero:

```
@foreach($mensajes as $m)
<textarea id="resp-hide" class="ultima-respuesta-hide" style="display: none">{{ $m->comment }}</textarea>
    <p id="ult-respuesta" class="ultima-respuesta"></p>
@endforeach
```

Este script es el que me traduce a texto plano por asi decirlo

```
<script>
    . var traducirHTML = document.getElementById("resp-hide").value;
      document.getElementById("ult-respuesta").innerHTML = traducirHTML;
    </script>
```

eso me muestra solo el texto y esta perfecto, pero cuando se ingresa otro comentario ya no funciona, solo funciona con un comentario, no muestra nada si es mas de un comentario, alguien sabe como hago para que me muestre los otros comentarios tambien pero sin las etiquetas? hay otra forma?

Answer (score 0):

creo que tu problema lo podrías solventar añadiendo ese script en una función y ejecutándola después de que se añada otro comentario, ej:

```
@foreach($mensajes as $m)
<textarea id="resp-hide" class="ultima-respuesta-hide" style="display: none">{{ $m->comment }}</textarea>
    <p id="ult-respuesta" class="ultima-respuesta"></p>
<script>traducir();</script>
@endforeach

<script>
function traducir() {
    . var traducirHTML = document.getElementById("resp-hide").value;
      document.getElementById("ult-respuesta").innerHTML = traducirHTML;
}
</script>
```

O lo que sería más correcto, intenta registrar el evento cuando se ingresa otro comentario, y que ejecute el script a continuación.